# initializing a spreadsheet, order of calculation

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a VBA code that solves a set of algebraic equations whose coefficient matrix is Tridiagonal (known as Thomas algorithm).  The equations have the form

A(i)X(i-1)+B(i)X(i)+C(i)X(i+1)=R(i)

The values of A, B, C, and R are passed to the function that returns the values of X.  The VBA code is below.

```
Option Base 1
Function TRIDI(ByVal Ac As Range, ByVal Bc As Range, ByVal Cc As Range, _
ByVal Rc As Range) As Variant
Dim BN As Single
Dim i As Integer
Dim II As Integer
Dim A() As Single, B() As Single, C() As Single, R() As Single, X() As Single
N = Ac.Rows.Count
ReDim A(N), B(N), C(N), R(N), X(N)
For i = 1 To N
A(i) = Ac.Parent.Cells(Ac.Row + i - 1, Ac.Column)
B(i) = Bc.Parent.Cells(Bc.Row + i - 1, Bc.Column)
C(i) = Cc.Parent.Cells(Cc.Row + i - 1, Cc.Column)
R(i) = Rc.Parent.Cells(Rc.Row + i - 1, Rc.Column)
Next i
A(N) = A(N) / B(N)
R(N) = R(N) / B(N)
For i = 2 To N
II = -i + N + 2
BN = 1 / (B(II - 1) - A(II) * C(II - 1))
A(II - 1) = A(II - 1) * BN
R(II - 1) = (R(II - 1) - C(II - 1) * R(II)) * BN
Next i
X(1) = R(1)
For i = 2 To N
X(i) = R(i) - A(i) * X(i - 1)
Next i
TRIDI = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(X)
End Function
```

The function works fine for linear equations.  If the equations are nonlinear, for example for the three equations below

X(1)=1

X(1)-2X(2)+X(3)=3+ X(1)^2

X(1)+X(3)=2

The solution is obtained iteratively using Excel’s iterative functionality, as shown below. (I can't yet post images, since this is my first post. If you email me, bumedoc@gmail.com, I can send you the spreadsheet too)

```
     A    B    C     D                  E

1    A    B    C     R                  X

2    0    1    0     =1          =TRIDI(A2:A4,B2:B4,C2:C4,D2:D4)

3    1   -2    1     =3+E2^2     =TRIDI(A2:A4,B2:B4,C2:C4,D2:D4)

4    1    1    0     =2          =TRIDI(A2:A4,B2:B4,C2:C4,D2:D4)
```

However, after saving the spreadsheet and opening it again, I get #value! Error in E2:E4 and D3.  I assume that upon opening the spreadsheet, Excel tries to initialize the cells that have circular reference and gets confused.  Does anyone have a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `=3+E2^2` with `=IFERROR(3+E2^2,0)` works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It takes care of the problem in this instance.  Is there a more general approach that performs the same function in the parent sheet from within TRIDI (or adding another function), avoiding the necessity of adding IFERROR to all the cells containing the values of A, B, C, and R?

Comment: Adding an error handler that forces the UDF to throw 0 in case of an error does the trick. It seems that writing UDFs can be tricky.. I found some information here: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsj.htm

Comment: I tried this, with no successFor i = 1 To N
        A(i) = Ac.Parent.Cells(Ac.Row + i - 1, Ac.Column)
        If (IsError(A(i))) Then A(i) = 1

Comment: After dimensioning the variables (after the Dim statements), add the following line:     
 `On Error GoTo errHandler`  
Then in the end, just before the 'End Function' line, add:  
`Exit Function  
errHandler:  
     TRIDI = 0`  
This directs the flow to the "errHandler" part whenever an error occurs, the function gets a 0 value and terminates. The IsError(A(i)) will check if A(i) is error type, but will not catch other errors elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Ioannis!  It did work and I really appreciate it.  I have been struggling with this for a while.  Thanks again.