# Passing rows or columns from a sheet to a VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a VBA code that solves a set of algebraic equations of the form

A(i)X(i-1)+B(i)X(i)+C(i)X(i+1)=R(i)

A portion of the function is given below.  Currently, the coefficients A, B, C, and R have to be stored in columns in the main worksheet to be passed to the function.   Is there a way to provide the flexibility of having the coefficients either in rows or columns?

```
Function TRIDI(ByVal Ac As Range, ByVal Bc As Range, ByVal Cc As Range, _
ByVal Rc As Range) As Variant
Dim BN As Single
Dim i As Integer
Dim II As Integer
Dim A() As Single, B() As Single, C() As Single, R() As Single, X() As Single
N = Ac.Rows.Count
ReDim A(N), B(N), C(N), R(N), X(N)
For i = 1 To N
A(i) = Ac.Parent.Cells(Ac.Row + i - 1, Ac.Column)
B(i) = Bc.Parent.Cells(Bc.Row + i - 1, Bc.Column)
C(i) = Cc.Parent.Cells(Cc.Row + i - 1, Cc.Column)
R(i) = Rc.Parent.Cells(Rc.Row + i - 1, Rc.Column)
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can add an optional variable to the function to indicate a column function.

Se example: **(Edited)**

```
Function TRIDI(ByVal Ac As Range, ByVal Bc As Range, ByVal Cc As Range, ByVal Rc As Range) As Variant


    Dim BN As Single
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim II As Integer
    Dim ColumnN As Boolean
    Dim A() As Single, B() As Single, C() As Single, R() As Single, X() As Single

    If Ac.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        N = Ac.Columns.Count
        ColumnN = True
    Else If Ac.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        N = Ac.Rows.Count
    Else
        Exit Function
    End If

    ReDim A(N), B(N), C(N), R(N), X(N)

    If ColumnN = True Then
        For i = 1 To N

            A(i) = Ac.Parent.Cells(Ac.Row, Ac.Column + i - 1)
            B(i) = Bc.Parent.Cells(Bc.Row, Bc.Column + i - 1)
            C(i) = Cc.Parent.Cells(Cc.Row, Cc.Column + i - 1)
            R(i) = Rc.Parent.Cells(Rc.Row, Rc.Column + i - 1)

        Next i
    Else
        For i = 1 To N

            A(i) = Ac.Parent.Cells(Ac.Row + i - 1, Ac.Column)
            B(i) = Bc.Parent.Cells(Bc.Row + i - 1, Bc.Column)
            C(i) = Cc.Parent.Cells(Cc.Row + i - 1, Cc.Column)
            R(i) = Rc.Parent.Cells(Rc.Row + i - 1, Rc.Column)

        Next i
    End If


End Function
```

I might have missed some of the functionality of your function in the example, but i think you get the point. If this does not work give me feedback and ill try another solution. :)

**Edit:** You can also make the function above a function that receives input form two other functions named CTRIDI and RTRIDI. These two functions just pas ether true or false to the column variable.

Comment: Thanks Ole - I was hoping for a more general and approach, transparent to the user.  For example, if you consider the Excel functions like MAX, AVERAGE,... you can pass the data in column for rows or combination.  How do these get the right values?

Comment: I'm on a mac right now so ill continue tomorrow, however you can check wheather the input range is multiple colums or miltiple rows and base the conditional variable on that.

Comment: I have edited my answer, but the code is completely untested, and from the top of my head. Also please clarify your question please, can you make maby createa a better example of what you want the result to look like?

Comment: Thanks! your solution sounds like it should  work, but I got an error that I am still trying to figure out.   The information about the function and what it does can be found at my earlier post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003202/initializing-a-spreadsheet-order-of-calculation

Comment: Good! glad i could help :)